# Why Is the Induced Map Not Zero?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading "Modern Classical Homotopy Theory" by Strom and have come across the following.  We are given a fibration $F\rightarrow E\rightarrow B$.  One then has two pushout squares:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F @>>> CF\\
@VVV @VVV \\
E @>>> E\cup CF
\end{CD}
$$
and
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
* @>>> *\\
@VVV @VVV\\
B @= B
\end{CD}
$$
There are clear maps between these squares, resulting in a cube (that I can't figure out how to draw using MathJax).  This gives a map between the pushouts $E\cup CF\rightarrow B$.  This came about when examining another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530981/question-about-transgression).  There I have 
$$
F\stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} E\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} B\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow K},
$$
where $E$ is the homotopy fiber of $f$ and $F$ is the homotopy fiber of $p$.

I am just hoping for someone to help clear up some of my confusion.  The composite
$$
E\cup CF\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow K
$$
needn't be nullhomotopic.  But it would seem from the pushout cube and the fact that $E$ is the fiber of $f$, that it must be.  Can someone explain why not?